# force single line in labels of microsoft reporting reports

Tags: report, multiline, microsoft-reporting

I have a report which was created using Microsoft Reporting in VS2010. It has labels which must display any text in single line. But it appears that if I don't set the label's height precisely correct, then the text will be displayed in lines bellow if it doesn't fit in a single line. I haven't found a property that enforces single line on labels. What are the ways  to enforce single line except setting proper height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be no other solution except setting CanGrow = false and guessing the correct label height.